# how to check for unused variables/functions in class

Tags: php, debugging, validation, variables

I have a large PHP class that has a large variable/function declaration and I wanted to chek if all the variables/functions are being used in the script. Is there something that does this?

Comment: https://www.exakat.io/en/removing-unused-variables-is-good/ This may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic nature of the PHP language (eval, using variables/functions via strings, etc...) makes it theoretically impossible to programmatically determine if a function or variable is ever used in any and all possible situations.

Manual code analysis is, unfortunately, your best bet.

Comment: It's a clever and no doubt correct answer, but for most coders I doubt there is a vast amount of this kind of fancy stuff going on. A tool that looks through your code to see whether the variable or function is explicitly referenced would serve most people well.

Comment: Even though php is dynamic there is nothing that prevent for checking if a variable is not used in a given scope (in a function for instance). Such tools help you to avoid mistakes in your code and to write better code.

Comment: Useless answer!

Answer (score 10):

You could use PHP Mess Detector [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/) with configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My first PHPMD rule set"
     xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0
                 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="
                 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">

    <rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml" />
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use code coverage tools like [PHP_CodeCoverage](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage), which is based on [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)'s statement coverage functionality, or unit testing software like [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) or [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/) (which have code coverage integrated).

You'd need to write many unit tests first, before you could test your code coverage, though.

Comment: These are both great going forward and can test if **certain** functions have been called but it won't test if a function or variable will **ever** be called.

Comment: @webbiedave: I agree that programmatic determination would be likely impossible when it comes to eval's, variable variables, etc. I agree too, that manual code analysis would be the way to go, if the class in question is relatively small (say up to 200 lines). But the OP did not state about how many code lines we're talking exactly. How will you keep track with manual code analysis if the class has 1,000, 10,000 ore more code lines? Imo, depending on the complexity and size of the class, using code coverage could be the more appropriate way.

Comment: 1000 lines of code is manageable -- albeit tedious -- for manual analysis. A 10K line class needs a serious refactoring! Regardless, I think it's a case-by-case situation where either manual, automatic, or maybe both are the way to go. We'd need to know more specific information about the class.